# How to substract 2 columns of unaligned data with Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two DataFrames

```
df1=

   x  y1
0  0   0
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  4   3


df2=

     x  y2
0  0.0   0
1  0.5   1
2  1.5   2
3  3.0   3
4  4.0   4
```

I need to calculate y2-y1 (for the same x value)
(in order to see the difference between 2 graphs)

As you can see, some values are in common between them... some are not

I think I will need to resample my data... but I don't know how !
I need to align data in order to have same 'x' column for the 2 dataframes.

between 2 points a linear interpolation should be done to get y value at a given x.

In this case resampling data with a x_step=0.5 will be good

I did this...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0],[4.0,3.0]],columns=['x','y1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0.0,0.0],[0.5,1.9],[1.5,2.0],[3.0,3.0],[4.0,4.0]],columns=['x','y2'])

print(df1)
print("="*10)
print(df1['x'])
print("="*10)
print(df1['y1'])
print("="*10)

fig = plt.figure()

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.title("{y} = f({x})".format(x='x', y='y'))
p1, = plt.plot(df1['x'], df1['y1'], color='b', marker='.')
p2, = plt.plot(df2['x'], df2['y2'], color='r', marker='.')

plt.legend([p1, p2], ["y1", "y2"]) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0],[4.0,3.0]],columns=['x','y1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0.0,0.0],[0.5,1.9],[1.5,2.0],[3.0,3.0],[4.0,4.0]],columns=['x','y2'])
x = np.union1d(df1.x, df2.x)
y1 = np.interp(x, df1.x, df1.y1)
y2 = np.interp(x, df2.x, df2.y2)
pl.plot(x, y1, "-o")
pl.plot(x, y2, "-o")
```

[image]

Comment: plot both y2 and df2['y2']... you will see that there is a problem  (with point x=2) ! http://pastebin.com/hipQCSZ4 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/203/capturedecran20130311a0.png/

Comment: It seems that `Series.interpolate()` doesn't use index value to interpolate the NaN values. So I changed the answer to use `numpy.interp()`.

Comment: Thanks it works fine... I just wonder why y1.interpolate() doesn't work well with NaN (and how nan data are interpolated !)... that's very strange.